# how to add single quotes to a variable value in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am creating simulink blocks programmatically. For this, I have the following loop.

My parameter name should be 'Input1' and not Input1.

I have already tried using '''input_name''' but this sets my parameter name to 'input_name'.

I want to read the value of input_name and put that into single quotes.

```
for i=1:num_of_input
  pos = [x y+offset*(i-1) x+w y+h+offset*(i-1)];
  input_increment = strcat('/Input', num2str(i));
  input_name = strcat('Input',num2str(i));

  add_block('testLibrary/Inport', [modelName input_increment], 'Position', pos);
  set_param([modelName input_increment],'param_name', input_name);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It was quite simple.

In the line where I concatenate the strings, I need to directly add a single quote :

```
input_name = strcat('''Input',num2str(i),'''');
```